# Merge 30000 polygon shapefiiles in a logical manner in ArcGIS model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, polygon, modelbuilder, merge

I have 30000 shapefiles (a1.shp to a30000.shp). They are all polygons. Each polygons has one and only one polygon feature in it. I need to [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) the polygons into 1000 shapefiles. My output would be 1000 polygons (each with 30 sequential polygons in it)

So output b1.shp = Merged polygons a1.shp to a30.shp

So output b2.shp = Merged polygons a31.shp to a60.shp

So output b3.shp = Merged polygons a61.shp to a90.shp

and so on up to...

b1000.shp = Merged polygons a29970.shp to a30000.shp

Looking for an ArcGIS model builder or GDAL solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be easier with [arcpy](/questions/tagged/arcpy).

```py
for i in range(10000):
    pol_list = []
    for j in range(30):
        pol_list.append("a" + str(i*30 + j + 1) + ".shp")
    arcpy.Merge_management(pol_list, "b" + str(i+1) + ".shp")
```

EDIT:

for a feature class inside a geodatabase, you don't need the + ".shp"  anymore, and you can define the workspace using :

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/geodatabase.gdb"
```

or you can concatenate the full paths

```py
outgdb = "C:/data/outgeodatabase.gdb/"
 ...
     arcpy.Merge_management(pol_list,outgdb + "b" + str(i+1))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is excellent. Could you possibly show me how to amend the code above so it would work with polygon features in a file geodatabase as opposed to shapefiles? Basically everything stays the same but now into and out of the scratch geodatabase as opposed to shapefiles.

Answer (score 0):

In ModelBuilder, you use [Iterate Feature Classes](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Classes/00400000000r000000/) to loop through the shapefiles, then use [Collect Values](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000005000000.htm) to send the iterator values to Merge.

It will look like this:

[image: model_builder]

Comment: I believe this model is incorrect despite the fact that it will work (but very inefficiently).The Iterator and Collects tool should be in a sub model with the Output Values exposed as a parameter. This sub model should then be in a master model feeding into the merge tool. As it stands Merge is being executed _X_ number of times rather than just once.

Answer (score 0):

Modelbuilder!

Add iterator: FOR
Set it to start at 10, iterate from 0-350 or so, in iterations of 30. Output of iterator will include Value variable.

Select by attribute, as so: 
FID = %Value%+1 or 
FID = %Value%+2 or 
FID = %Value%+3 or 
etc.

For the FIDS:
First iteration: 0+1, 0+2, 0+3
Second iteration: 30+1, 30+2, 30+3
Third interation: 90+1, 90+2, 90+3

After the select features, merge them.